# Make sure you are using the latest version of SafariLauncher that appium is using

Tags: ios, mobile-safari, appium

I want to do mobile browser automation on real iOS device using Appium. Here are the steps I have followed:

1. I cloned Safari Launcher project from https://github.com/snevesbarros/SafariLauncher and successfully installed Safari launcher app into the iPhone 6.
2. Copied the Safari launcher.app file and zip the file and then copy the zip file into the Safari launcher folder in this path:

   ```
    Appium\Contents\Resources\node_modules\appium\build\SafariLauncher
   ```
3. Set `ios_webkit_debug_proxy` successfully and connected to my I-Phone.
4. When I run the appium; it connects to the device and open the Safari launcher app on the device; but then the following error was thrown:

   > Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: Error. Could not find button to launch Safari. Make sure you are using the latest version of SafariLauncher that appium is using.

Other details:

- Appium version: 1.4.13
- X-code version: 7.3
- I Phone 6 iOS version: 9.3
- Enable UI Automation set to Yes in Developer mode.
- Web inspector is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you are using compatible version of Safari browser and appium.